# How do I save in Silent Hill 2?

Tags: silent-hill-2

I started playing Silent Hill 2 through my PlayStation Now subscription. I got pretty far in to the game, and when I closed out of it, it made me restart the game.

I've been far enough to load checkpoints, but I cannot figure out how to save.

How do I save in Silent Hill 2?

Comment: Hey, Carmen. Welcome to the Arqade! Ive tried to answer your question - I cant see why playstation now would specifically alter the way the game saves, and I could see how you had fallen into the problem you describe, given my experience with the original game. If Ive missed the mark, and my answer doesnt help, let me know.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I’ll see if that works! 

Comment: Not a problem. Just make sure to come back and tick the green tick to the left of my answer if it does help, to let others know it worked for you in the future

Answer (score 2):

Saving in Silent Hill 2 works a bit differently to what you may be familiar with in other, more recent, games.

Firstly, saving is not automatic. If you do not tell your game to save, it will not save. Secondly, you need to be at one of multiple specific locations to save. You can't just save wherever you like.

It's been a while since I last played Silent Hill 2, so I referred to the Fandom page to double check the specifics:

> ### Silent Hill 2
>
> In [Silent Hill 2](https://silenthill.fandom.com/wiki/Silent_Hill_2), the save point takes the form of a [small, bright red rectangle](https://silenthill.fandom.com/wiki/Red_Square) and is the same size as [Mary's letter](https://silenthill.fandom.com/wiki/Mary%27s_Letter). It can found for the first time inside a well, in the beginning of the game. At first glance, it looks like a simple, red sheet of paper, sometimes stuck on walls.
>
> [image]

---

As a final note, I recall that the number of saves you make affect the final score, when you complete the game. This should not alter the ending you receive, but if you are trying to get a good end score, you may want to try to limit the number of times you save.

I have not found any confirmation that this was actually the case for Silent Hill 2; I can confirm that it was for Silent Hill and various other survival horror games that came out around the same time.